# How can I speed up a large MySQL update query?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm attempting to write what I think should be a rather straightforward `UPDATE` query, but it's taking *much* longer to run than I'd expect.

I have a `collections` table, and a second table called `collections_users`. The latter is an association table that records associations between collections and users. Users that are associated with a collection are called "followers". The query in question stores a snapshot of each collection's follower count with the collection record. Here's my first attempt:

```
UPDATE collections C
SET C.follower_count_summary = (
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM collections_users CU
  WHERE CU.collection_id = C.id
);
```

Related info:

- The query currently takes about 45 seconds to run.
- All columns (`C.id`, `C.follower_count_summary` and `CU.collection_id`) have indexes.
- The `collections` table has 326k records.
- There are only 7 `collections_users` records at the moment, though this will grow quite a bit.
- MySQL version info: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.25a, for osx10.7 (i386) using readline 5.1

Is there a way around this massive query time, or is this just the time it takes to run a query like this?

Comment: Is there an index on C.id?

Comment: My guess is that the index on follower_count_id will slow it down rather than speed it up. This is because it cannot be used to lookup (meaning, it will not speed things up), but it is being changed (meaning it will slow things down. If you need it for other reasons, that's fine; but, you don't need it for this update.

Comment: not need this index) and update too, need `cu.afterinsert/cu.afterdelete` triggers

Comment: @DariusX.: Interesting. I *do* need the index to speed up a runtime use case where I'll be sorting by that column, but nice to know the tradeoffs I'm making. Thanks!

Comment: and afterupdate too, if collection_id can changed... 3 triggers for one counter actualization)

Comment: @vp_arth Thanks for the comment. As I commented on TomTom's answer below, I'd rather not use runtime triggers to accomplish this.

Comment: Hey, just wondering why this question got down-voted. Care to explain why, down-voter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt will do one sub query for each row in **collections**, that's why it takes a long time. You should be able to see that with `explain update...`if you are using mysql 5.6.

I think the best solution is to either maintain the counts through a trigger or to snapshot them into another table (MySQL is picky about writing and reading the same table in one query). Then you could snapshot like this

```
replace into collections_counts
 select C.id, count(1)
   from collections C
   join collection_users CU on (C.id = CU.collections_id)
  group by C.id;
```

Then just join in that table on every fetch of collection

Comment: I hadn't been aware of the issue with writing and reading from the same table. I'll try creating a separate table and report back. Thanks!

Comment: @hoffm, was this faster? It seems it would be slower than the original due to overhead of replace (which deletes then inserts). `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY` might make sense if you really must insert rather than merely update.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Sorry for the delay; running it now as I type. Nope, not faster. Took 54.5s. EDIT: For transparency, here's the new command I ran:

    UPDATE collection_stats CS
    SET CS.follower_count = (
      SELECT count(*)
      FROM collections_users CU
      WHERE CS.collection_id = CU.collection_id
    );

Answer (score 2):

Not a MySQL Person but here is a sql server general solution:

**DO** not do the update.

I do that on multiple occasions, **using triggers to maintain the count**. This has the advantage that this type of query is super fat because no updates must be done.

Comment: The reason for doing it in one fat update is that I don't want this work being done at runtime. I'd rather do it once a day, as that would provide current-enough data for my use case without adding weight to my application. A 45-second query nightly isn't the end of the world, but I figured there's probably a more efficient way to do, and I'd like to know what it is if so.

Comment: interesting, wrap you it into transaction?

Comment: @vp_arth In sql server triggers are automatically part of the transaction doing the update (which may be intrinsic but the update of the original table is atomic as per sql acid quarantees and that atomicity extends to all trigger operations).

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with something like:

```
UPDATE collections C INNER JOIN (SELECT  CU.collection_id, 
    count(*) cu_count
FROM collections_users CU) cu2 ON C.id = cu2.collection_id
SET C.follower_count_summary =  cu2.cu_count;
```

However I'm not in front of MySQL at the moment and can't double check this with EXPLAIN....so it's a guess

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have an index on C.id?

I think the problem is with the WHERE CU.collection_id = C.id which is being executed for each line (with the select count).

P.S. - try checkin the execution plan, make sure it makes sense - it might be that the statistics are not current, so the plan is not using indexes at all...